# MySQL move or archive unused data

Tags: mysql

So I have decent size table with transactions. I can not redesign it or add more indexes. Data as is. Half of business logic do full scan anyway.
I get an idea to move some old/unused data to 'archive table' to speed up stuff a little and be able once in a while scan all data anyway. Or other direction around: create 'fast table' where I will have only fresh (last month or so) data, and normal table which will have all data.

Is anyone aware of this kind of technic or anything? Where to read? better approaches? How to implement in code or something.

For now we have around 50 mil rows of data with crazy partitions which made more harm then use.

```
PARTITION BY LIST (user_id%20)
SUBPARTITION BY KEY (user_role)
SUBPARTITIONS 4
(PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES IN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES IN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES IN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES IN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p9 VALUES IN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES IN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES IN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES IN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p13 VALUES IN (13) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p14 VALUES IN (14) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p15 VALUES IN (15) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p16 VALUES IN (16) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p17 VALUES IN (17) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p18 VALUES IN (18) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p19 VALUES IN (19) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

Where 3 different user_role and around 20 rows per uniq user_id. Do not ask me what the hell, it just is what it is....

Thank you.

PS: I absolutely understand it is better invest time to fully analyze and redesign table itself, however sometimes it's impossible 'cuz of politics and simple shitty people who above you in food chain.

Comment: Maybe take a look at partitioning. But either way, this question is beyond the scope of SO. Those chaps in dba might be able to help.

Comment: As @Strawberry suggests, partitioning by date should help. You can ALTER TABLE by adding partitioning and also query of specific partition which would speed up some queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into [Table Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html)
, specifically [Range Partitioning:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html)

If you *partition* you table by the date column/timestamp, Mysql will then only  scan an appropriate partition, during the query:

> You frequently run queries that depend directly on the column used for partitioning the table. For example, when executing a query such as EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE separated BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-12-31' GROUP BY store_id;, MySQL can quickly determine that only partition p2 needs to be scanned because the remaining partitions cannot contain any records satisfying the WHERE clause.

Comment: We tried partitioning, somehow it made thing worse )

Comment: @AlexanderMatrosov Please add some information on what did you try to your question, then. Partitioning does work, and is efficient, taking that it is done right.

Comment: The usual gotcha is when you run queries which can not be satisfied by selecting data from one partition only (i.e. queries which involve a different key or `OR` condition), but in this case creating an `archive` table by hand would be of little help either.

Comment: I guess, if we made simple partitions by date it should help. Kinda archive table and fast table in one.

Comment: @AlexanderMatrosov Yep, if you can define the "unused data" in terms of calendar dates, just change your partitioning schema to use that.

If you want to avoid rewriting existing queries to include the correct date range condition, you may try to define some views to overcome that (e.g. 
rename the table to _Partitioned and define a "fresh data only " view using it's original name, so that any existing queries will only see the "fresh" subset of data).